# each_with_index desired column output Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, foreach

```
<% source.strains.each_with_index do |strain, j| %>
 <% if (j == (source.strains.size - 1)) %>
  <font size="3">Strain <%= strain[0].appendix %> </font>
 <% end %>                       
<% end %>
```

I need to get output as

If j value is last one of a loop, then i need to print first value of loop (j[0]). Kindly suggest me or correct above script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your code is the same as

```
<font size="3">Strain <%= source.strains.last[0].appendix %> </font>
```

(Without any loop)

Check out [Array#last](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#M000403)

But even if you didn't know about `last` method, making a loop to access last element in collection is kinda weird. You can, at least, do `collection[collection.size - 1]`.

**on comment**
Then why're you doing `strain[0]` instead of `source.strains[0]`? `source.strains` is your collection and `strain` is just a current element in the loop. I thought `strain` is some kind of array too.

Comment: I dont need to print last one. "last" will be used for printing last one. I need to print first element if last element occurs.

Comment: May be that will be an issue... Please correct me according to need.

Comment: @Palani Have you tried **taking first element from your collection**? Just like above, _collection[0]_.